TabView background will not display fullscreen
I have a background applied to my ContentView. That works great. No surprise there.
I have a TabView.
I want to apply a single background, and have it visible no matter which tab is selected by the user.
Seems straightforward, but I cannot make it work.
Here's the code:
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            BackgroundImageView()
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            VStack{ 
                TabView {
                    HomeView()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                    ListingView()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "clipboard.fill")
                                .imageScale(.large)
                        }
                    SettingsView()
                        .background(Color.clear)
                        .tabItem {
                            Image(systemName: "gearshape.fill")
                                .imageScale(.large
                        }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

struct HomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text("Home")
            Spacer()
        }
        .background(Color.clear)
    }
}



How it renders is that I can see that the background image is fullscreen, but the HomeView renders a large rectangle (black in dark mode) with the "Home" text in the center, and a tab bar.
The other tabs exhibit similar behavior.
I'm sure that it's something simple that I'm missing.
